# Background Panel Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I hope you can help me with this problem, attached videos to explain in a simpler way.

[First example](http://youtu.be/Qz-3CcoKKqc)

Panel (has a textured background) with labels (the labels have a png image without background) 
Events: `MouseDown`, `MouseUp` and `MouseMove`.
As you will notice in the video to drag the label the background turns white panel and regains its background image when I stop dragging the label

Panel controls have a transparent background as property, but changing the background with any color, let the problem occurred related to the substance, I do not understand why this happens and how to fix less.

[Second Example](http://youtu.be/fZgPps6QVBY)

Contains the above, with the only difference that the panel controls instead of having transparent background, I chose black color for that property

Answer (score 0):

You have to use double buffer and you don't have to stop using an image on the background, you can have everything running smoothly.

You have a couple of ways to do this, the fast way (not enough most of the time) is to enable `doublebuffer` of the panel.

The "slow" but better way is to do your own Double Buffer using a Bitmap object as a buffer.
This example creates a "side buffer" and accepts an image as parameter and draws it using created buffer.

```
public void DrawSomething(Graphics graphics, Bitmap yourimage)
{
    Graphics g;
    Bitmap buffer = new Bitmap(yourimage.Width, yourimage.Height, graphics);
    g = Graphics.FromImage(buffer);
    g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

    g.DrawImage(yourimage, 0, 0);

    graphics.DrawImage(buffer, 0, 0);
    g.Dispose();
}
```

Call this on your OnPaint event.

BTW... this is just a double buffer example.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Change DoubleBuffered to true for both form and panel. I think that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

this is totally normal, because `System.Windows.Forms.Control` based items were not designed to do this kind of advanced Graphics operations.
in fact the reason that this effect happens here, is that when you assign any value other than 255 to the alpha component of a control `BackColor`, the form does the following when you change the control size or position:

1. it sets the new control position
2. it redraws the parent control
3. it gets the background of the control's parent as an image
4. it draws acquired image into the control body to seem as if the control is transparent
5. the control body gets drawn on top of the previously drawn background
6. the control children are drawn

**** this is is a simplified explanation for the sake of illustration to deliver the idea***

steps 1, 2 are responsible for the flickering effect that you see.

but you have two ways to solve this,

-the first is some kinda advanced solution but it's very powerful, which is you would  have to create a double buffered custom control that would be your viewport.

- the second is to use **WPF** instead of windows forms, as **WPF** was designed exactly to do this kind of things.

if you can kindly provide some code, i can show you how to do both.